# Angular 4 Routing Change Animation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-animations

I'm trying to do simple fade animation on route change, but it doesn't work.

My animation file it's like this:

```
export class RouterAnimations {
    static animate() {
        return trigger('routerTransition', [
            state('void', style({ opacity: 0 })),
            state('*', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            transition(':enter', [
                style({ opacity: 0 }),
                animate('0.4s ease')
            ]),
            transition(':leave', [
                style({ opacity: 1 }),
                animate('0.4s ease')
            ])
        ]);
    };
};
```

My component's like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../vitrine.component.css', './home.component.css'],
  animations: [RouterAnimations.animate()]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('@routerTransition')
  public routerTransition = true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I observed that if I put a `position: fixed` on states, it works, but when the animation is completed the view is fixed and the layout is broken in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: 'relative'` on `state('*',style({position: 'relative', opacity: 0 }))`

```
import {trigger, state, animate, style, transition} from '@angular/animations';

export function fade() {
   return trigger('routerTransition', [ 
        state('void', style({position: 'fixed', opacity: 0 })), 
        state('*', style({position: 'relative', opacity: 0 })), 
        transition(':enter', [ style({opacity: 0}), animate('0.4s ease', style({opacity: 1})) ]), 
        transition(':leave', [ style({opacity: 1}), animate('0.4s ease', style({opacity: 0})) ])
   ]);
}
```

in your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../vitrine.component.css', './home.component.css'],
  animations: [fade()]
})
export class HomeComponent {

  @HostBinding('@routerTransition') routerTransition;
  // ...

}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the opacity in states and it worked, but the animation suddenly completes without wait the time configured.

Comment: Try to move your home content to a child component and let HomeComponent to handle the animation only

Comment: Same problem, the animation stops suddenly.

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? on enter or on leave?

Comment: @tiagor87 I update the answer, try the updated animation

Comment: I changed and almost worked. So I did a little change and worked better.

return trigger('routerTransition', [
        state('void', style({position: 'fixed', opacity: 0 })),
        state('*', style({position: 'relative', opacity: 0 })),
        transition(':enter', [
            style({opacity: 0}),
            animate('0.4s ease', style({opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
            style({opacity: 1}),
            animate('0.4s ease', style({opacity: 0}))
       ])
    ]);

Comment: Thankyou very much.